# How to dock a VB6 form on the MS Word Task Pane?

Tags: ms-word, vb6

We are creating an Add-In to Microsoft word. In this Add-In there is a mode less form and we set it as the Top Most form too as per the requirement. In this case I want to dock this mode less VB6 form on the task pane of the MS Word Application.

If anyone has an idea  about how to do it,  Please let me know.

I have mentioned the code block currently I am using.

```
Public Sub ShowTheDialog()
Dim Test As Long
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

With frmSelectStyle
 .aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=Me
 .Show vbModeless
End With

Test = SetTopMostWindow(frmSelectStyle.hWnd, True)

ErrorHandler:
'Some code here 
 End Sub
```